# Is it profitable to mine Ethereum on AWS?

Tags: mining, ethereumj, aws

I got $5000 on AWS from Facebook by being part of FbStart. Since I wont be using these credits for web development, I want to know if it would be profitable for me to mine Ethereum? Can I at least make $5000? If so how long would it take?

Comment: Make sure to check the rules to use the credit, usually it doesn't allow such things as mining.